# Custom For-Each Sequence-like activity

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, activitydesigner

We use WF in our system to provide users with the ability to construct their own flows with some specialised 'building-blocks' (aka activities) that we provide them.

The task is to create a custom activity which behaves this way:

- it's immediate content is like regular Sequence, i.e. can contain a
  collection of child-activities.
- it has an input argument of type string-list. For simplicity say it is just a single long string of words separated with spaces.
- the actual behaviour is to execute the children for-each word in the list. The current-word should be accessible to the children's in-argument using an implicitly declared variable called "CurrentItem".

I hope this is clear in any way.
If not, please ask and i'll try to explain better.

So, does any one have any idea how can I accomplish this?
I've tried few approaches but no success, every time it fails on some other restriction this FW posses.

Thanks allot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I would build a composite activity with an entry point that parses the string and records the number of arguments.
This then passes execution to a switch activity that uses the argument from the string to direct execution to a child-activity which on completion then loops back to the parser activity to obtain the 2nd argument.
Then back to the switch, child activity, loop back process.

Once the parser activity runs out of arguments you exit the composite activity.